# linq latests elements that match a criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that looks like this:

```
 ActionID | ActionTime | ActionType | UserID
    1       3/22/2013        4          8
    2       3/31/2013        1          8
    3       4/12/2013        3          8
```

Each Action has several ActionTime and I want to get all the ActionIDs by users where the **latest** ActionTime is of some ActionType.

This is the query I have but as I'm testing it, it's not working as expected:

```
var TheActionType = list of bytes (ie. [1, 3, 5])

(from a in MyDC.Actions
 where a.UserID == TheUserID
 where TheActionType.Contains(a.ActionType)
 orderby a.ActionTime descending (//I only want the last ActionTime each user)
 select a.ActionID).ToList();
```

So if I'm passing in [4,1] in the ActionType, I shouldn't get anything back because the last ActionTime has an ActionType of 3.

Basically, I know I could redo this by first taking the lastest ActionID using `orderby` and `.FirstOrDefault()` and then running a second `.Contains()` query with the list of bytes, but I was wondering if there's a way to do this with just one query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
MyDC.Actions
    .GroupBy(x => x.UserID)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.ActionTime)
                  .First())
    .Where(x => TheActionType.Contains(x.ActionType))
    .Select(x => x.ActionID);
```

This does the following:

1. Groups the actions by `UserID`
2. For each user, selects the action with the highest `ActionTime`, in other words: It selects the youngest action.
3. The result is filtered by the list of allowed action types.
4. The `ActionID` is selected from the remaining actions.

Example: http://ideone.com/KbwPBI

I removed the filter by User-ID, because you said

> I only want the last ActionTime each user

So this query returns the last action ID for each user if it matches the specified action types.

If you really want only the latest action of a single user, you can simply add that `Where` in the previous query:

```
MyDC.Actions
    .Where(x => x.UserID == TheUserID)
    .GroupBy(x => x.UserID)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.ActionTime)
                  .First())
    .Where(x => TheActionType.Contains(x.ActionType))
    .Select(x => x.ActionID)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hm.. I'd `.where().groupby().select(... => .orderby.first.actionid)`. Merging the select()s is mostly cosmetical, but where-before-groupby may significantly limit the amount of data the groupby has to process. Filtering is light&streamed, grouping has to buffer everything! (I mean, in typical cases) (especially with sorting)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: That would yield different results. You first need to group and order that group to get the latest action per user. Only then you are allowed to filter by the action type.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is what I needed! Thanks for the answer. What do you think is going to perform better for filtering the UserID: a GroupBy() or a Where()

Comment: The `GroupBy` is not about filtering the userID

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: you're right. I missed the **"is"** in "the last Action is of some ActionType" and read it as "the last Action of some ActionType". I've thought the filter is a top level one in which case my suggestion would fit nicely. Here, surely the groupby/orderby must be done first.

Comment: BTW, .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.ActionTime) doesn't work

Comment: @frenchie: It should, I tested it. You can even see it working on the link. What is your problem with it?

Comment: @frenchie: In that case you don't have the same query as in my answer, please double check. Most likely, you are missing the `GroupBy`.